# connect to a gitlab using gitlab java api

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

I´m very "dummy" about gitlab , my question my sound stupid ... but where it goes ..

I would like to connect to a gitlab repo using java , the idea is just to retrieve the list of "entry´s" of the repository

I have seem some java code, but I´m not sure what will the url the send to "connect" method .

using the web browser the url is something like this https://gitlab.zzz.com/

example  :

```
  public static GitlabSession connect(String hostUrl, String username, String password) throws IOException {
        String tailUrl = GitlabSession.URL;
        GitlabAPI api = connect(**hostUrl**, null, null, null);
        return api.dispatch().with("login", username).with("password", password)
                .to(tailUrl, GitlabSession.class);
    }
```

Also, I only have the user and password .. no oauth token .. is possible to connect without the token ?

I sorry for my dummy questions, may some of you can give some tips how to start.

Thank you
Roque

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to get data from Gitlab is through Gitlab API (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html). According to documentation you get token first using your username and password. Further you use this token to access other resources

Comment: thank you , but "my" problems start on the url to connect  using the  https://gitlab.zzz.com/ , username and password I get this error  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target .. in this case what the url would be ?

Comment: You should use Gitlab certificate to encrypt your request, or write your code such as you TRUST all certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GitLab4J (https://github.com/gmessner/gitlab4j-api) to do this.  It allows you to connect with a username and password and internally handles the returned session token.

```
// Create a GitLabApi instance to communicate with your GitLab server
GitLabApi gitLabApi = GitLabApi.login("http://your.gitlab.server.com", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

// Get the list of projects your account has access to
List<Project> projects = gitLabApi.getProjectApi().getProjects();
```

Comment: thank you , but i´m no longer in project  that where this was required , didn´t have any feedback from the "project manager" about how they resolved this .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to gitlab using following Java gitlab API.For this, you need to  Allow firewall.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")`enter code here`
public class GitlabController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String getGitData() throws GitLabApiException {

        System.out.println("going to execute gitlab api..");
        GitLabApi gitLabApi = GitLabApi.login("https://gitlab.<domain>.com/", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
        User currentUser = gitLabApi.getUserApi().getCurrentUser();
        System.out.println(currentUser.getUsername());
        return "returning from git Controller";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please let me kow on how do you allow firewall for https url